# Retrofit string array sending object representation instead of value in request.

Tags: java, android, jackson, retrofit, retrofit2

I am using Retrofit 2 with Jackson converter in my Android project with the following request:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@PATCH("foo/{id}")
Call<FooModel> apiCallWithArrayOfStrings(@Path("id") int id, @Field("array_of_strings") List<String> array);
```

Here are the values that I pass to the interface method:

```
// the array of strings @Field param
ArrayList<String> arrayOfStrings = new ArrayList<>();
arrayOfStrings.add("1.2");
// the id param
int id = 2;
```

I run the app, have the API call perform the request, then retrieve the request via [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/).

Here is the issue. The request param "array_of_strings" is being sent using the object reference, not the actual value of the array objects:

```
// charles request shows:
array_of_strings [I@41fea508
// instead of:
array_of_stings ["1.2"]
```

How do I get Retrofit/Jackson to use the value of the array objects instead of the object reference value?

Comment: how should the body look like ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Via rom4ek's comment in this answer, using `ArrayList<String>` as the parameter type was the solution. Jackson must serialize ArrayLists differently than arrays or Lists.

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@PATCH("foo/{id}")
Call<FooModel> apiCallWithArrayOfStrings(@Path("id") int id, @Field("array_of_strings") ArrayList<String> array);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should just add `[]` brackets to `array_of_strings` field name, so Retrofit will know that you're going to send an array and will properly transform it to array field:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@PATCH("foo/{id}")
Call<FooModel> apiCallWithArrayOfStrings(@Path("id") int id, @Field("array_of_strings[]") List<String> array);
```

Comment: Great idea. I have tried that as well. Same result happened.

Comment: Hm, could you try to change `List<String>` to `ArrayList<String>` in parameters of the method?